# IEnumerable.except error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two `IEnumerable<dynamic>` of data retrieved from database tables, called `FullSet` and `InScopeSubSet`  .

The second `IEnumerable<dynamic>` is a subset of the first set (both sets have `ChildID` as their unique ID)

I would like to create a new `IEnumerable<dynamic>` that contains only items from x that do not occur in y

I have tried the following but it will not compile. It says:
*"extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax"*

```
 var sql = "SELECT ChildID, FirstName, Surname FROM Child ORDER BY ChildID ASC";
 var FullSet =  DB.Query(sql);

 sql = "
 SELECT UserScope.ChildID, Child.FirstName, Child.Surname 
 FROM UserScope 
 INNER JOIN Child ON UserScope.ChildID=Child.ChildID 
 WHERE UserAccountID = @0 ORDER BY ChildID ASC
    ";
 var InScopeSubSet = DB.Query(sql, UserAccount.UserAccountID);

 var OutScopeSubSet  = FullSet .Except(InScopeSubSet );
```

Comment: What is DB and what type does DB.Query return? It's not returning a (typed) IEnumerable or would wouldn't be getting this error.

Comment: Database.Query. Return value is Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object)
The rows returned by the SQL query.

Comment: Note that to get your `< >` angle brackets to appear, you *must* format the text as code (as I have done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10147958/revisions) )

Comment: I'm a bit confused, though: I can run `IEnumerable<object>.Except(IEnumerable<object>)` with no problem; can you check the actual types of those two variables at run-time and make sure they are what you expect?

Comment: Ah, nm, I see they are `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield the problem is that the objects are `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and as the error message says, you can't do dynamic binding on extension methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the compiler error, use its second suggestion:

```
var OutScopeSubSet = Enumerable.Except(FullSet, InScopeSubSet);
```

> The Enumerable one runs ok but returns the whole first set without taking out any items.

If that's the case, you are probably getting reference comparisons on objects that are not identical.  You might be able to do it by implementing a custom IEqualityComparer.  The call becomes

```
var OutScopeSubSet = Enumerable.Except(FullSet, InScopeSubSet, new DynamicChildIdComparer());
```

And DynamicChildIdComparer is:

```
class DynamicChildIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return ((dynamic)x).ChildID.Equals(((dynamic)y).ChildID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return ((dynamic)obj).ChildID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you.The Queryable one returns an error: best overloaded method match for 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except<object>(System.Linq.IQueryable<object>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>)' has some invalid arguments.                           The Enumerable one runs ok but returns the whole first set without taking out any items.

Comment: if Query is returning an `IEnumerable<object>` then the first one will not work; the problem seems to be that you are getting back `object` and it has no way of determining if two of those "rows" are "equal".

Comment: @CharlotteCopper the Queryable version won't run because the variables are IEnumerable, not IQueryable.  I overlooked that when I posted the answer, sorry; I've removed the bad example.  Please also see the edited answer for an idea about the incorrect results.

Comment: Yes it is an IEnumerable<object> returned from the database.Query. How can I compare them?  thanks

Comment: @CharlotteCopper refresh your page; I edited the question about a minute before you posted your last comment. :-)

Comment: Oh wow that works great THANK-YOU LOADS (now I need to try and understand why/how)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a "not in" SQL type operation

"Not in" in LINQ can be implemented like this :

```
var filterData = new List { "ListA", "ListB" };
var data= context.table.Select( c => c.id ).Except( filterData );
```